# amplitude,time values from an audio signal

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing

How can we get the amplitude,time values of an audio signal in java. I need to detect the peaks in the signal using these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one web page describing the most common .wav(RIFF) file format:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Just unpack the array of samples from the file and convert the data type and/or endianess, as needed. Then you need to average or filter the absolute value or squared value of a set of PCM samples covering the time window of interest.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to calculate the [root mean square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of the sound signal over a given time slice.